# In an OpenAPI Specification, Is there any industry standard to group the Resources(ResourceDefinitions) with their corresponding Endpoints?

Tags: endpoint, openapi

In an OpenAPI Specification, Is there any industry standard to group the Resources(ResourceDefinitions) with their corresponding Endpoints? Presently, I am using the paths of POST methods considering them to be Resources and comparing it to the individual endpoints but it is missing few endpoints. I have also tried to group them using tags but tags are not unique to each resource.

Here is the code: ep is the instance of Endpoint List and res is of ResourceDefinition List

```
if (StringUtils.startsWithIgnoreCase(ep.getEndpoint(), StringUtils.substringAfter(res.getPath(), ":"))) {
                    endpoint.setEndpoint(ep.getEndpoint());
                    endpoint.setMethod(ep.getMethod());
                    endpoint.setSummary(ep.getSummary());
                    endpoint.setDescription(ep.getDescription());}
```

All I need to know is, What is the criteria for grouping endpoints under their resources?